# bulk insert list values with SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

I'd like to bulk insert a list of strings into a MySQL Database with SQLAlchemy Core.

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://...")
meta = MetaData()
meta.bind = engine
```

My table layout looks like this - together with two currently unused columns (irrelevant1/2):

```
MyTabe = Table('MyTable', meta,
Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), 
Column('color', Text),
Column('irrelevant1', Text)
Column('irrelevant2', Text))
```

Unfortunately the following does not work - it inserts an empty row. What's the right way to do this?

```
MyTable.insert().execute(['blue', 'red', 'green'])
```

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [Executing Multiple Statements](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements)

Comment: For very fast insertions, look into using the lower level `session.bulk_insert_mappings(Table, lst)` See the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#session-and-sessionmaker).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
MyTable.__table__.insert().execute([{'color': 'blue'}, 
                                    {'color': 'red'}, 
                                    {'color': 'green'}])
```

Or, using `connection.execute()`:

```
conn.execute(MyTable.insert(), [{'color': 'blue'}, 
                                {'color': 'red'}, 
                                {'color': 'green'}])
```

You can easily make a list of dicts from the list you have:

```
[{'color': value} for value in colors]
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible to just use the list (no dictionaries)?

Comment: @fanti well, [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements) says that yes, this should be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @fanti why don't just make a list of dicts from the list, like I've noted in the answer?

Comment: @alecxe: Is there a way to pass _hints_ to the bulk insert statements in SQLAlchemy? so that I can make it even faster? For Eg.: `/*+append*/` in Oracle helps bulk inserts speed up much faster.

Comment: This [results in an `executemany` DBAPI call](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements), which is usually converted to multi-value `INSERT .. VALUES (..), (..), (..)` statement (e.g. see [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)). According to the [sqlalchemy's FAQ](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow), this is the fastest you can get without using DB-specific bulk loading methods.

Comment: ...I believe sqlalchemy doesn't provide an API to use bulk-loads, you [have to use dialect-specific APIs for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34523707/1026).

Comment: Which variant would be faster?

Comment: maybe this helps someone later,

we need to use __table__ to access the Table object that is underlying in the class. i.e. MyTable.__table__ = table is equivalent to the Table('MyTable'), meta,....) construct of the classical sqlalchemy method. And insert is a method of the classical Table

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do it:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://....")
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['MyTable'])
table = Table('MyTable', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

engine.execute(table.insert(), [{'color': 'blue'}, 
                            {'color': 'red'}, 
                            {'color': 'green'}])
```

Comment: It's metadata and not meta in the Table initialization no?