# Import CSV to database using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394998/using-sqlalchemy-to-load-csv-file-into-a-database) example to upload a csv file into a sqlite database:

this is my code:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from time import time
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float, Date, String, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

def Load_Data(file_name):
    data = genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',')# skiprows=1, converters={0: lambda s: str(s)})
    return data.tolist()

Base = declarative_base()

class cdb1(Base):
    #Tell SQLAlchemy what the table name is and if there's any table-specific arguments it should know about
    __tablename__ = 'cdb1'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    #tell SQLAlchemy the name of column and its attributes:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False) 
    name = Column(VARCHAR(40))
    shack = Column(VARCHAR)
    db = Column(Integer)
    payments = Column(Integer)
    status = Column(VARCHAR)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = time()
    print 'creating database'

    #Create the database
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///cdb.db')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    #Create the session
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    s = session()

    try:
        file_name = 'client_db.csv'
        data = Load_Data(file_name)

        for i in data:
            record = cdb1(**{
                'name' : i[0],
                'shack' : i[1],
                'db' : i[2],
                'payments' : i[3],
                'status' : i[4]
            })
            s.add(record) #Add all the records

        s.commit() #Attempt to commit all the records
    except:
        s.rollback() #Rollback the changes on error
        print 'error in reading'
    finally:
        s.close() #Close the connection
    print "Time elapsed: " + str(time() - t) + " s." #0.091s
```

and this is the first few rows of the csv file:

```
Name,Shack,DB,Payments,Status
Loyiso Dwala,I156,13542,37,LightsOnly ON
Attwell Fayo,I157,13077,32,LightsON
David Mbhele,G25,13155,33,LightsON
```

The DB is created ok, but only some of the data is captured into the attributes: the 'payments' and 'db' column are populated correctly, but everything else comes out as NULL.

UPDATED CORRECT CODE (using pandas dataframe):

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from time import time
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float, Date, String, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import csv
import pandas as pd


#def Load_Data(file_name):
    #data = csv.reader(file_name, delimiter=',')# skiprows=1, converters={0: lambda s: str(s)})
    #return data.tolist()

Base = declarative_base()

class cdb1(Base):
    #Tell SQLAlchemy what the table name is and if there's any table-specific arguments it should know about
    __tablename__ = 'cdb1'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    #tell SQLAlchemy the name of column and its attributes:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False) 
    Name = Column(VARCHAR(40))
    Shack = Column(VARCHAR)
    DB = Column(Integer)
    Payments = Column(Integer)
    Status = Column(VARCHAR)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///cdb.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
file_name = 'client_db.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df.to_sql(con=engine, index_label='id', name=cdb1.__tablename__, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Try to use`module csv` instead of `numpy`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you familiar with Pandas Dataframe?

Really simple to use (and debug)

[pandas.read_csv(file_name)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
In [5]: pandas.read_csv('/tmp/csvt.csv')
Out[5]: 
           Name Shack     DB  Payments         Status
0  Loyiso Dwala  I156  13542        37  LightsOnly ON
1  Attwell Fayo  I157  13077        32       LightsON
2  David Mbhele   G25  13155        33       LightsON
```

For inserting the DataFrames data into a table, you can simply use  [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

So your main code will end up looking something like this:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///cdb.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

file_name = 'client_db.csv'
df = pandas.read_csv(file_name)
df.to_sql(con=engine, index_label='id', name=cdb1.__tablename__, if_exists='replace')
```

You should read further in the documentation link I added, and set the function Parameters as suits your purpose (specially look at - if_exists, index, index_label, dtype)

Comment: I am aware of pandas dataframes... what would be the bext way to insert the dataframe into the database?

Comment: great, works perfectly. Have updated with updated code

Comment: Isn't this solution restricted only to small csv file/tables/dbs?

Comment: Downvoted, this is extremely inefficient and will take hours for large tables.

Comment: For very large tables, this approach will exhaust your memory and crash.

Comment: As of version 0.24.0 you can pass `method='multi'` to pass multiple values in a single `INSERT` clause. (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html))