# How to speed up the import of csv to sql?

Tags: python, mysql

This is CS50 Web Project1 stage where I have to import books.csv (containing isbn, title, author and year) with 5000 lines in it. The problem is that the import itself takes too long (about 10 lines per second) and it's not normal I suppose. How do I speed it up?

I have created a table with isbn, title, author and year rows all in varchar. I use postgesql. Next I wrote import.py , which looks like this

```
import csv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker


engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    f = open("books.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for ISBN, title, author, year in reader:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO books (ISBN, title, author, year)      VALUES (:ISBN, :title, :author, :year)",
       {"ISBN":ISBN, "title":title, "author":author, "year":year})
    db.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I expect the import to proceed in less than a minute, but now it's about 30-40 minutes.

Comment: Create a transaction and hence insert into the database as a bulk operation. Finally commit the transaction.

Comment: @jens1o could you please describe this solution in more details? I'm only beginning my path in handling databases)

Comment: You should check the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/persistence_techniques.html#bulk-operations) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659142/bulk-insert-with-sqlalchemy-orm)

Answer (score 0):

Given the performance you're observing (10 rows/ second), I would guess the latency of a request to your database is rather high (check it with `ping`). If that's the case, inserting multiple rows in a single query using `INSERT .. VALUES (..), (..), (..)` should help a lot.

To do that, you have to:

- Pass a list of values to insert to `execute`: `db.execute(sql_query, list_of_dicts_here)`
- Assuming you use psycopg2 to connect to Postgres, you need to [tell sqlalchemy to use psycopg2's "fast execution helpers"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-executemany-mode) by passing `executemany_mode='values'` to `create_engine`

If your file was larger, I would suggest to look into using ["COPY FROM"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34523707/1026) bulk loads, but there's no point doing that with only 5000 rows.