# Improve pandas' to_sql() performance with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I come to you because i cannot fix an issues with **pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()** method.

I've made the connection between my script and my database, i can send queries, but actually it's too slow for me.

I would like to find a way to improve the performance of my script on this. Maybe someone will find a solution?

Here is my code :

```
  engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(con['sql']['connexion_string'])
  conn = engine.connect()
  metadata = sqlalchemy.Metadata()
  try : 
    if(con['sql']['strategy'] == 'NEW'): 
      query = sqlalchemy.Table(con['sql']['table'],metadata).delete()
      conn.execute(query)
      Sql_to_deploy.to_sql(con['sql']['table'],engine,if_exists='append',index = False,chunksize = 1000,method = 'multi')
    elif(con['sql']['strategy'] == 'APPEND'):
      Sql_to_deploy.to_sql(con['sql']['table'],engine,if_exists='append',index = False,chunksize = 1000,method = 'multi')
    else:
      pass
  except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
```

It's working and too slow when i retire chunksize and method parameters,it's this moment where it's too slow (**almost 3 minutes for 30 thousand lines**). When i put these parameters, i get an `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError...`

thanks for your help !

Comment: Which database back-end are you using?

Comment: Are you using mssql / pyodbc?

Comment: You might want to post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ its more focused on this kind of request

Comment: I'm using SQL Server, with mssql+pyodbc as a windows authetification.

Comment: Are you using "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"?

Comment: Only SQL Server, when i write ODBC 17 for SQL Server, it send me an error that there is no driver...

Comment: For no reason (didn't change the code) to_sql() method just stop working, even for small data...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `mssql+pyodbc` you will get the best performance from `to_sql` if you

1. use Microsoft's ODBC Driver for SQL Server, and
2. enable `fast_executemany=True` in your `create_engine` call.

For example, this code runs in just over 3 seconds on my network:

```py
from time import perf_counter
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

ngn_local = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://mssqlLocal64")
ngn_remote = sa.create_engine(
    (
        "mssql+pyodbc://sa:_whatever_@192.168.0.199/mydb"
        "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
    ),
    fast_executemany=True,
)

df = pd.read_sql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM MillionRows WHERE ID <= 30000", ngn_local
)

t0 = perf_counter()
df.to_sql("pd_test", ngn_remote, index=False, if_exists="replace")
print(f"{perf_counter() - t0} seconds")
```

whereas with `fast_executemany=False` (which is the default) the same process takes 143 seconds (2.4 minutes).

Comment: Thank you so much, i've taped fastexecutemany against to fast_executemany...

Comment: And indeed, pass from 300 secondes to 14 for 50k rows, it's clearly better ! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I synthesised a dataframe with 36k rows.  This always inserts in < 1.5s.  Also a dumb `select` with expensive `where` clause and a `group by` which gets marginally slower as table grows but always < 0.5s

1. no indexes so inserts are fast
2. no indexes to help selects
3. running on mariadb inside a docker container on my laptop.  So not all all optimised
4. all defaults which is performing well

More information

1. what indexes do you have on your table? rule of thumb fewer is better.  More indexes, slower inserts
2. what timings do you see from this synthesised case?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random, time
import sqlalchemy

a = np.array(np.meshgrid([2018,2019,2020], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 
                     [f"Stock {i+1}" for i in range(1000)],
                    )).reshape(3,-1)
a = [a[0], a[1], a[2], [round(random.uniform(-1,2.5),1) for e in a[0]]]
df1= pd.DataFrame({"Year":a[0], "Month":a[1], "Stock":a[2], "Sharpe":a[3], })


temptable = "tempx"

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://sniffer:sniffer@127.0.0.1/sniffer')
conn = engine.connect()
try:
#     conn.execute(f"drop table {temptable}")
    pass
except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:
    pass # ignore drop error if table does not exist
start = time.time()
df1.to_sql(name=temptable,con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
curr = conn.execute(f"select count(*) as c from {temptable}")
res = [{curr.keys()[i]:v for i,v in enumerate(t)} for t in curr.fetchall()]
print(f"Time: {time.time()-start:.2f}s database count:{res[0]['c']}, dataframe count:{len(df1)}")
curr.close()
start = time.time()
curr = conn.execute(f"""select Year, count(*) as c 
                        from {temptable} 
                        where Month=1 
                        and Sharpe between 1 and 2 
                        and stock like '%%2%%'
                        group by Year""")
res = [{curr.keys()[i]:v for i,v in enumerate(t)} for t in curr.fetchall()]
print(f"Time: {time.time()-start:.2f}s database result:{res} {curr.keys()}")
curr.close()
conn.close()
```

**output**

```
Time: 1.23s database count:360000, dataframe count:36000
Time: 0.27s database result:[{'Year': '2018', 'c': 839}, {'Year': '2019', 'c': 853}, {'Year': '2020', 'c': 882}] ['Year', 'c']
```

Comment: Actually i don't have index on my sql because i put the parameter to false.And on my database i don't have index to check neither.
Clearly i juste have to put throught the table my data. But my data is in integer and string. and i have a column in Datetime in my database, maybe it's this? But for few data it's working. I don't why so it's not working with big...

Comment: the example I've done is strings and floats.  I added a datetime column to it as well and no change to times (as expected).  what DBMS are you running and is it far away on the WAN?

Comment: What do you mean by WAN?

Comment: WAN = wide area network, LAN = local area network.  How separated is your python pandas from your DBMS?  ODBC interfaces are typically *chatty* so important to design your infra setup such that middle tier data management functions are "close" to your DBMS.  The whole point of multi-tier application design