# Bulk inserting in python using SQLAlchemy and Pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

I am migrating from using pyodbc directly in favor of sqlalchemy as this is recommended for Pandas. I could do a simple `executemany(con, df.values.tolist())` to bulk insert all rows from my pandas dataframe into a SQL Server table. After migrating, this is what I currently have:

```py
def insert_into_table(self, con: sqlalchemy.Connection, table: str, df: pd.DataFrame):

    # Create insert statement
    query = f"INSERT INTO {table} (" + ",".join(df.columns) + ") VALUES (" + ",".join(["?"] * len(df.columns)) + ")"

    # Replace nan to None to prevent insert errors
    df = df.replace({np.nan: None})

    # Insert all rows
    con.execute(statement = sqlalchemy.text(query), parameters = df.to_dict(orient = "records"))

    # Commit the table
    con.commit()

    return
```

The error returned by the con.execute statement is: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Expected 31 parameters, supplied 0', 'HY000')`

The query is correct and below is some example of the `df.to_dict(orient = "records")` output:

[image]

Not sure what else is missing... any help is appreciated.

Thanks

I am expecting that `con.execute()` insert all dataframe rows into a SQL Server table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dataframe.to_sql()`

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/DATABASE")

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.to_sql(name='dbtable_name', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

I use mysql in my codes,you can change db what you want

Comment: to_sql is very slow.. bulk inserting is many times faster

Comment: SQL Server  db  try to enable `fast_executemany=True `  in your `create_engine`, here is the link about bulk insert question 
1.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171038/improve-pandas-to-sql-performance-with-sql-server/63178240#63178240)
2.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997859/bulk-insert-a-pandas-dataframe-using-sqlalchemy)